# Voices in videos too low. Random volume changes [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, sound

I'm having a lot of sound issues and I'm not sure how to debug this properly to find a solution.

Sound volumes are sometimes fine and then they get lowered and the sound is distorted. Then after turning up the volume randomly the sound will jump back to normal.

The Speaker Testing for Analog Output from the System Settings > Sound prompt always works properly. I can reproduce the bad sound most of the time by runing:

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_center.wav
```

Any ideas as to how I can proceed?